Why reading the contents of a socket takes so long to finish
Context
I am currently making a program in Linux that uses SSL secured IPv4 sockets. Once the sockets are created they connect to an IP and make a request
socket->Connect( ip.c_str() , port );
socket->Write(  request.c_str(), strlen(request.c_str()) );

After that I read the contents of the page in a loop with a buffer then I accumulate the contents of the buffer in a string. The buffer also cleans in each iteration to avoid overwriting the contents.
int bytes_read = 0;
char buffer[buffer_size]; // where buffer_size is an arbitrary number 512 for example
do {
    bytes_read = socket->Read(buffer, buffer_size);
    result += buffer;
    // std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
} while (bytes_read > 0);

The code is pretty simple, as I said I use sockets with SSL connections but I do not use any extra flag on the socket. But once the program is run it take a considerable amount of time to finish even when connecting to pretty simple pages.
As a result of that I decided to type the content of the buffer in each iteration and I noticed that the program reads the content almost instantly but the program run for another 5 seconds before finishing it's execution. In bigger pages like Wikipedia it doesn't finish as I have to do Ctrl^z.
Therefore my question is, why is this happening? I don't understand this behavior,the man page of read says as follows:

On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates
end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.
It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of
bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes
are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to
end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a
terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal

From what I understand once the EOF is reached it will return a 0 and then it should exit out of the loop.
The expected behaviour is of course to exit out of the loop once the contents have been read. As a matter of fact if I just do the read one time instead of looping through it the program finishes in < 1 seconds. This is however something I don't want to implement as the function read can fail and not read all the bytes specified in size and I need to ensure that all the contents of the page are read.
What I have tried
So far I've tried to use a timeout in the socket
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 10; // 10 secs
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

if (setsockopt(socket->getDescriptor(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt failed");

Aswell as making it non blocking
int flags = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);

But it has not worked. I would like to understand why is this happening and how can I ensure that all the contents of a page are read without having this problem where the program won't end or will take a lot of time. I appreciate the help thank you.
Edit
Full piece of code of the program

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  (void) argc;

  Socket* socket;
  std::string ip = argv[1];
  std::string request = argv[2];
  int port = 443;
  const int buffer_size = 1024;
  std::string result = "";



  socket = new Socket();    // Create a new stream socket for IPv4
  char buffer[buffer_size];
  memset( buffer, 0, buffer_size );
  socket->Connect( ip.c_str() , port );
  socket->Write(  request.c_str(), strlen(request.c_str()) );
  int bytes_read = 0;

  do {
    bytes_read = socket->Read(buffer, buffer_size);
    result += buffer;
    memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
  } while (bytes_read > 0);

Where the ip and request are passed in a fork by another program either way they are hard coded so it's like calling this one.

Is the extra socket->Read call before bytes_read = socket->Read intentional? Seems like you might lose data that way. Would probably help to see a [mcve] we could test with.

No it isn't that was a mistake when posting it is commented in my code. I'm gonna try to bring a reproducible example but this code is part of a bigger program that works with multiple forks so it can be kinda messy.

So this isn't the real code. So post the real code.

I added all the code, apologize for not posting it since the beginning I thought it would obstruct the real question.

Eh? Posting more code than really exists 'would obstruct the real question'? How? NB You are ignoring the case when read() returns -1, indicating an error: instead you are doubly appending the previous buffer. You need to answer the question about whether this is really HTTP.

Regarding of what hobbs said, yes I am requesting HTTP/1.1. But how can I be able to send the header Connection: close  I know I can do it with the write function, but in that while loop what could be the condition that would indicate it's time to close the connection, since asking if bytes_read == 0 would cause the same effect.

Sigh. If you send the Connection: close header, the server will close the connection, and your read() will return zero, which is when your loop will exit, after which you should close the connection. Most of this has already been stated.

I understand that... but I don't know when should I send that, I don't know if it is before entering the loop, during the loop and if it is during the loop under what condition I need to do this to make sure it's sent once all the content was read, since before this read will not return 0. I apologize for poorly structuring my question I'm new to this page and I did my best to follow the correct format...

You should send the Connection: close header along with all the other headers. Not during the read loop at all. It's a header. It's part of the request.

Ok I think I get it now, thank you for bearing with me and for your help, I will try to implement it in that way.

I did it, it worked. I added it to the request next to the host and it worked thank you for your help.

You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP. Far more than you've exhibited so far.

You haven't said outright, but it seems like you're talking about HTTP (particularly, HTTP/1.1), so I'll proceed on that assumption.
You're waiting until the connection is closed, but the connection isn't closed after the response is sent (and ordinarily, it shouldn't be). Eventually though, the server gets tired of waiting for you to send something else, and closes the connection. How long that takes is up to the server.
The correct way to read an HTTP response is to actually understand the HTTP protocol: read and parse the headers, then read Content-Length bytes worth of body if that's set, or read chunks until a 0-length chunk is reached if Transfer-Encoding contains chunked.
If you're unable to do that, you can send the header Connection: close to indicate that you won't be sending any more requests on the connection, and that the server should close the connection after sending its response, but that's an inefficient way to do anything.
